# How to get the result of an operation exposed as a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm parsing some exif data of an uploaded photo.

In the exif data I have a string: 11/5

I need to convert this string in the result of 11 / 5, so 2.2. As float.

Is there an easy way or I need to extract 11, 5, then convert to float and then execute the division?

Comment: _"Is there an easy way or I need to extract 11, 5, then convert to float and then execute the division?"_ IMHO that's an easy way. You can do it with `'11/5'.split('/').reduce((lhs, rhs) => parseInt(lhs) / parseInt(rhs));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.Function() like:

```js
function looseJsonParse(obj){
    return Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')();
}

console.log(looseJsonParse('11/5'))
```

Comment: You shouldn't post an answer with a comment "But never do this".

Comment: @ThomasSablik it depends on the use case.

Comment: _"Never use eval()!"_ is pretty clear. There is no valid use case. At least you should replace `eval` with `window.Function`. That depends on the use case.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Right I update my answer with the correct way.

Comment: I wouldn't call it the correct way and it probably wouldn't pass any serious code review. It's just a little bit better than `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

May be this one help

```
let string = '11/5'
let stringArray = string.split('/')
let ans = parseInt(stringArray[0]) / parseInt(stringArray[1])
ans = parseFloat(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

A short and easy way is

```
'11/5'.split('/').reduce((lhs, rhs) => parseInt(lhs) / parseInt(rhs));
```

or

```
'11/5'.split('/').map(n => parseInt(n)).reduce((lhs, rhs) => lhs / rhs);
```

Examples:

```js
console.log('11/5'.split('/').map(n => parseInt(n)).reduce((lhs, rhs) => lhs / rhs));

console.log('11/5'.split('/').map(n => parseInt(n)).reduce((lhs, rhs) => lhs / rhs));

const f1 = str => str.split('/').reduce((lhs, rhs) => parseInt(lhs) / parseInt(rhs));

console.log(f1('11/5'));

const f2 = str => str.split('/').reduce((lhs, rhs) => parseInt(lhs) / parseInt(rhs));

console.log(f2('11/5'));
```